# DeviseCreateUsers: migrating create_table(:users) rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake

I encountered the following error while running `rake db:migrate --trace`. my rails version - rails 3.2.0. And i am trying to run the project https://github.com/ninetwentyfour/Hospitium. I am newbie to ruby to ruby on rails

**errors:**

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Invoke disable_rails_admin_initializer (first_time)
** Execute disable_rails_admin_initializer
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  **DeviseCreateUsers: migrating** ==============================================
-- **create_table(:users)**
**rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
undefined method `database_authenticatable'** for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapte
rs::TableDefinition:0x5d49098>
E:/ruby projects/Hospitium Animal Hospital/db/migrate/20110904205556_devise_crea
te_users.rb:4:in `block in up'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:160:in `create_table'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:422:in `create_table'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:450:in `block in method_missing'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:424:in `block in say_with_time'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in `measure'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:424:in `say_with_time'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:444:in `method_missing'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:334:in `method_missing'
E:/ruby projects/Hospitium Animal Hospital/db/migrate/20110904205556_devise_crea
te_users.rb:3:in `up'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:358:in `up'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:396:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in `measure'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:396:in `block in migrate'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:118:in `with_connection'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:377:in `migrate'
C:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:704:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:761:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:761:in `ddl_transaction'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:703:in `block in migrate'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:684:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:684:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:554:in `up'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:535:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie
s/databases.rake:153:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_lev
el'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handlin
g'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handlin
g'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

My GEM file

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem "eventmachine", "1.0.0.beta.4.1"
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'devise' # Devise must be required before RailsAdmin
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'mechanize'
gem 'uuidtools'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.3.4'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'paper_trail'
gem 'oauth'
#gem 'twitter'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'json'
#gem 'libxml-xmlrpc'
gem 'bitly'
gem 'site_meta'
gem 'meta_search'
gem 'airbrake'
gem 'spork', '~> 1.0rc'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'jqplot-rails'
gem 'asset_sync'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag'
gem 'best_in_place'
gem 'juggernaut'
gem 'jquery-rails'
#gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
gem "spreadsheet", "0.6.5.8"
gem 'to_xls'
gem 'sanitize'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'rqrcode-rails3'
gem 'octokit'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'closure-compiler'
end

group :development do
    gem 'metrical'
end

group :production do
    gem 'home_run', :require=>'date'
    #gem 'slim_scrooge', :git => "git://github.com/sdsykes/slim_scrooge.git"
    gem 'dalli'
    gem 'thin'
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'newrelic_rpm'
    gem 'heroku'
end

gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:test, :development]
group :test do
    gem "factory_girl_rails"
    gem "capybara"
    #gem 'capybara-webkit'
    gem 'shoulda-matchers'
    gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
    gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem 'launchy'
    gem 'email_spec'
end

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

as per Said Kaldybaev solution , i tried

```
E:\ruby projects\Hospitium Animal Hospital>rails g devise:install
conflict  config/initializers/devise.rb
Overwrite E:/ruby projects/Hospitium Animal Hospital/config/initializers/devise.
rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] h
Y - yes, overwrite
n - no, do not overwrite
a - all, overwrite this and all others
q - quit, abort
d - diff, show the differences between the old and the new
h - help, show this help
Overwrite E:/ruby projects/Hospitium Animal Hospital/config/initializers/devise.
rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] a
force  config/initializers/devise.rb
identical  config/locales/devise.en.yml
===============================================================================

Some setup you must do manually if you haven't yet:

1. Ensure you have defined default url options in your environments files. Her
e
is an example of default_url_options appropriate for a development environm
ent
in config/environments/development.rb:

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

In production, :host should be set to the actual host of your application.

2. Ensure you have defined root_url to *something* in your config/routes.rb.
For example:

   root :to => "home#index"

3. Ensure you have flash messages in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
 For example:

   <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
   <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

1. If you are deploying Rails 3.1 on Heroku, you may want to set:

   config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

   On config/application.rb forcing your application to not access the DB
    or load models when precompiling your assets.

   ===============================================================================

   E:\ruby projects\Hospitium Animal Hospital>rails g devise user
     invoke  active_record
   Another migration is already named add_devise_to_users: E:/ruby projects/Hospiti
   um Animal Hospital/db/migrate/20120518093709_add_devise_to_users.rb

   E:\ruby projects\Hospitium Animal Hospital>rake db:migrate
   ==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
   -- create_table(:users)
   rake aborted!
   An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

   undefined method `database_authenticatable' for #

   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to problem with that repo at that time, https://github.com/ninetwentyfour/Hospitium,
now its working fine.